# Relation between CompanyInfo and LogisticsElectronicAddress

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I want to make a query to get the information of an actual company and put it in a report. I need to get the full name of company, address, phone number and fax.

I tried to get some information about my company from the table "CompanyInfo" but we don't have a field to get phone or fax. I tried a display method, but the method returned nothing!

I want to make a relation between "CompanyInfo" and "LogisticsElectronicAddress" (I can find phone or fax from LogisticsElectronicAddress.Locator where LogisticsElectronicAddress.Type == phone (or fax)).

Can someone please help me to make a display method or query to get what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't make it harder:

```
Str phone = CompanyInfo::find().phone();
Str address = CompanyInfo::find().postalAddress().Address;
Str zip = CompanyInfo::find().postalAddress().ZipCode;
```

Will find the current phone number, address and zip code of the current company.

If `phone` is blank then the phone number is not current. Make sure the phone number is marked "Primary" and that it is valid (in a valid time range as indicated by the `ValidFrom` and `ValidTo` fields.

In AX 2012 from "Legal entities", "Contact information", choose "More options" and "Advanced" to see the date rages.

Same thing with the address info.

Comment: You have a data problem, read the rest of the answer. The standard function only returns the "Primary" phone.

Comment: plzz JB can you explain what role of the static methode FIND() in AX2012 ? and the logic of combination of methode and feild ! (methode1().methode2().field; => for exp : CompanyInfo::find().postalAddress().Address;)

Comment: A `find` method does what it does, but should return a record found using the parameters, if any. So `CompanyInfo::find()` finds the `CompanyInfo` record of the current company, which has a method `postalAddress` wich returns the current address record of that. Then pick a field of that record, fx `Address`.